# Converting many perl files to a single executable file

Tags: perl, exe

I have 10 perl programs written for processing a data in multiple steps. while one program gives some output, which is used by the next one.
I want all my programs to run in series while protecting the original code.

**So far** I have converted 10 *perl* files to 10 *exe* files. Still have to run them via *batch* file.
I want to merge all exe files to one, so that
I do not have to care: *If all files are in same folder or not.*

Can anybody suggest, any other way to append all perl files to a single executable file, directly.

Comment: Could you convert the batch file to an exe using a tool like http://download.cnet.com/Bat-To-Exe-Converter/3000-2069_4-10555897.html ? Also, what is the problem with having it as batch file?

Comment: @Disco3 I may distribute the project as an application. and I want users to run execution in single file like every other software package.

Comment: @Nari2 (1) Could you explain what you mean by “… while protecting the original code”? Does this mean that you don't want to change your code to make it easier to distribute, or that you want to distribute as a closed-source program? (2) Why is the code split across 10 scripts? Wouldn't it make more sense to refactor the code to use Perl modules? This would also make packaging easier…. Or do you need parallelism, and you only know how to achieve this with batch files?

Comment: @amon I am developing an application which may get a publication. I just want to show another group how it works not what is inside (or what language I used for program)

Answer (score 0):

You need so-called packer, check google for "EXE Bundle", there are tools for that.

Comment: Cava packager is best but it converts 1 file at a time not many.

Comment: Check other ones, it may join several EXE files. Write me to Artem.Razin (at) gmail.com, I'll write you about one particular tool. I could write here, but moderators wrote me that it's a kind of advertising :)

Answer (score 0):

**I found a way to do what I wanted.**
1. I *concatenated* text code of all perl files into another **single text file** renamed it as *file.pl*
2. I took care that each *file handler* is *closed* after its need is over.
3. I also took care that the name of file handler *should not repeat* in the same file.

**Note:**

```
use strict;  
use warnings;
```

may give lot of headache.
But the program is working.
*Then I converted this code to EXE application.*

Thanks